# How can I dynamically call a method on an object with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have the following code:

```js
const selectors = {
  posts: {
    getAllPosts(): Post[] {
      return database.findPosts();
    },
    getPostsWithStatus(status: Post["status"]) {
      return database.findPosts({ status });
    }
  },
  users: {
    getCurrentUser(): User {
      return database.findUser();
    }
  }
};
```

I want to create a function to call one of the nested methods so I can do something like:

```js
const deletedPosts = select("posts", "getPostsWithStatus", ["deleted"]);
```

So far here is my implementation:

```js
type Selectors = typeof selectors;

function select<
  SelectorType extends keyof Selectors,
  SelectorFn extends keyof Selectors[SelectorType]
>(
  selectorType: SelectorType,
  selectorFn: SelectorFn,
  args: Parameters<Selectors[SelectorType][SelectorFn]>
): ReturnType<Selectors[SelectorType][SelectorFn]> {
  return selectors[selectorType][selectorFn](...args);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOZkG8CwAUMssACYBcy2UoA5gNxEnZxgCumVARGRADYRIZbsgA+ydiD4xQEMk0IBfIkVCRYiFAFVM0PM1KVqYWiEZEVhIgnQhs1ARARh0UTMgC8B4sgAOWGBcPiQkdEIAgvz8GNiYABQAlFSxYADaALohoSRQQuxQIMiZijlKADSGYUKpmADqwGAAFgDKYGyc8awcwalp3N2c3BmJ2Tl5HIXFGaWhViQVhpzQwQS+1WAAwgV54LrQSVT7UGOhEwVFuEY8AIyiSrMLhlYPqoRgAJ5+KC1OLm4ebyfb7oGCOQT-dyKIgwKQuYB2cHOMAAHkMvwhrigABUvigIAAPSDSDwAawgH1ByAxyIBlV8NMhADEioTiWQyRSqYysZg0jy3LjvhkiAA+eKGPSYwV4qgCnF4+ksP5YllylVuFlK5BwKB0Xq6uAAWyEKxR8r58qFEAy-I1UBZGVFRGSyAASvlCtbzfbLfbrbb5Y7RdlzlMpbT3GkI5CA9H7Y74gA6FO6-WJRRWGx2Bx8QTCWpeJEueLcAJxbjlZDccJgWoNZptDqYSvFXhOYTDDNAA)

The types are properly inferred when calling the function but the implementation itself raises errors:

```
args: Parameters<Selectors[SelectorType][SelectorFn]>
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> Type '{ posts: { getAllPosts(): Post[]; getPostsWithStatus(status: "deleted" | undefined): never[]; }; users: { getCurrentUser(): User; }; }[SelectorType][SelectorFn]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.

```
): ReturnType<Selectors[SelectorType][SelectorFn]> {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> Type '{ posts: { getAllPosts(): Post[]; getPostsWithStatus(status: "deleted" | undefined): never[]; }; users: { getCurrentUser(): User; }; }[SelectorType][SelectorFn]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.

```
return selectors[selectorType][selectorFn](...args);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> This expression is not callable.

So my question is, how can I create a function that dynamically calls another one nested in an object while preserving the types?

Comment: "the implementation itself raises errors" Please clarify and detail these errors in order for the code here to be a [mre]; the playground link is a good supplement, but we can't *require* someone navigate away from SO to get details about the question.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that you'll be able to write this without [type assertions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and other workarounds.  You're running into a combination of [ms/TS#21760](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760) and [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  [This](//tsplay.dev/mq1k2m) would be my suggested approach here.  Anything else you do to try to get more type safety will probably be more of a headache.  Does this address your question and I should write up an answer? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, your answer is definitely on point! Please feel free to write it up so I can mark it as resolved. And sorry for not sharing the errors, I was afraid it would cause more confusion but I'll keep it in mind next time.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.  You can [edit] your question to share the errors, so that you have a [mre].  You don't have to wait until next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into a few limitations and pain points of TypeScript, and the best way to deal with it is probably to work around them.

---

The first is a known bug, filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760).  The compiler isn't able to follow the constraints of nested [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) where the key type is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  I'm not sure if or when this will be fixed.

So, if `K extends keyof Selectors` and `P extends keyof Selectors[K]`, then the compiler has forgotten that `Selectors[K][P] extends (...args: any) => any`, so you can't pass it to [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) or [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype), whose type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to that function type.

Instead, we can write our own unconstrained versions of `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>`.  The [implementation of `Parameters<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/18ac37221bed1a60cf16a2c6f84dd9b2bed1e206/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1526) is like `T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never`, so we can just use that directly (but I'll change `P` to `A`):

```
function select<
  K extends keyof Selectors,
  P extends keyof Selectors[K]
>(
  selectorType: K,
  selectorFn: P,
  args: Selectors[K][P] extends ((...args: infer A) => any) ? A : never
): Selectors[K][P] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never {
  return selectors[selectorType][selectorFn](...args); // still error
}


const deletedPosts: Post[] = select("posts", "getPostsWithStatus", ["deleted"]);
```

Now the call signature of `select()` has no errors and you can still call it.  But the implementation still has an error, which brings us to our second pain point.

---

This is a general type of limitation, filed as [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  There is a *correlation* between the types of `selectors[selectorType][selectorFn]` and the type of `args`, but the compiler is unable to follow that.  The compiler is unable to perform arbitrary analysis on types, and it does not know that a function `f` or type `F` and a value `a` of  type `Parameters<F>` can be called like `f(...a)` if `F` is generic, or if it is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of function types.  The compiler doesn't do a case-by-case analysis of every possible `K` and `P` type parameter.  For every possible call to `select()`, the line `selectors[selectorType][selectorFn](...args)` is valid, but the compiler does not analyze that line multiple times.  It does so once, and it is not seen as type safe because it's too complex.

There is a fix at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) that allows you to refactor code to represent these correlations as generic operations on some base type.  But I can't get this to work for your code, probably because of the same nested generic index problem from before.

So instead of trying to get the compiler to see the correlation, we will just take the responsibility away from the compiler and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), like this:

```
return (selectors[selectorType][selectorFn] as any)(...args);
```

Using [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) like this is often overkill, but the "correct" assertion is a complicated mess and doesn't really provide any type safety.  No matter what you assert, remember that type assertions are a way for you to tell the compiler not to worry about something it can't figure out... and therefore you should be sure *you* have figured it out.  Double and triple check that `selectors[selectorType][selectorFn](...args)` is always safe before asserting.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOZkG8CwAUMssACYBcy2UoA5gNxEnZxgCumVARGRADYRIZbsgA+ydiD4xQEMk0IBfIkVCRYiFAFVM0PM1KVqYWiEZEVhIgnQhs1ARARh0UTMgC8B4sgAOWGBcPiQkdEIAgvz8GNiYABQAlFSxYADaALohoSRQQuxQIMiZijlKADSGYUKpmADqwGAAFgDKYGyc8awcwalp3N2c3BnJaIGZ2Tl5HIXFGaWhViQVhpzQwQS+1WAAwgV54LrQSVRHUJOh0wVFuEY8AIyiSgvLhlbPqoRgAJ5+KC1OFxuDzeH5-dAwRyCIHuRSfIgwKQuYB2KHOMAAHkMAGlkBAAB6QaQeADWEG+EOQAOhrnclV8qDxhIgxOQZIpkOp6OBaWxGSIAD54oY9DS3AAVX4QKjY+ksQG0gBiIBScuQcCgdGCXJhmF5GTSqCyBKJZA88XiADprRqtVRQDB9BFEl4BeqQN8XQB+ZARZBUEAQABu0CIox1tL1fMNxuZrKtNs1wTgHpdnjdDv0ACVkD6cwHg-pNiQAPQltG6tKi7lQSV-A3VmHKjIJy22zCJBjIMsmYDRPFQKBuQxXWZdBU8xu0usQBsTqDN9UeFOe1vtzuWT62ew4PiCYS1FLjLLeKfxbgBOLccrIbjhMC1BrNNodTDX4q8JzCYadoA)